# timer to do some operation and not call a method?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I obviously know how to use NSTimers, and cocos2d timers , such as :

```
[self schedule: @selector(updater:) interval:0.5];
```

but all this timers call a function. i dont want that .

i need a timer that **within my method** will count, and at the end, will do one operation such as toggle a BOOL , or change an integer.

is there a simple way to do that in 1 line ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@interface CCScheduler (BlockAddition)

- (id)scheduleAfterDelay:(ccTime)delay block:(void(^)(ccTime dt))block;

@end

@interface NSObject (BlockAddition)

- (void)cc_invokeBlock:(ccTime)dt;

@end

@implementation NSObject (BlockAddition)

- (void)cc_invokeBlock:(ccTime)dt {
    void(^block)(ccTime dt) = (id)self;
    block(dt);
}

@end

@implementation CCScheduler (BlockAddition)

- (id)scheduleAfterDelay:(ccTime)delay block:(void(^)(ccTime dt))block {
    block = [block copy];
    [self scheduleSelector:@selector(cc_invokeBlock:) forTarget:block interval:0 paused:NO repeat:0 delay:delay];
    return block;
}

@end
```

---

example

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].scheduler scheduleAfterDelay:0.1 block:^(ccTime dt) {
     NSLog("time's up");
}];
```

or if you are using older version of cocos2d

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleAfterDelay:0.1 block:^(ccTime dt) {
     NSLog("time's up");
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the schedule call and unschedule it so it did not keep getting called... like this:

```
#import "SchedulerBlock.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@implementation NSObject (BlockAddition)

- (void)cc_invokeBlock:(ccTime)dt {
    void(^block)(ccTime dt) = (id)self;
    block(dt);
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleSelector:_cmd forTarget:block];
}

@end

@implementation CCScheduler (BlockAddition)

- (id)scheduleAfterDelay:(ccTime)delay block:(void(^)(ccTime dt))block {
    block = [block copy];
    [self scheduleSelector:@selector(cc_invokeBlock:) forTarget:block interval:delay paused:NO];
    return block;
}
@end
```